# NSBox background image

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbox

How can I set background image a for an `NSBox`? I know we can put a color, but what about background image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [+NSColor colorWithPatternImage:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSColor/colorWithPatternImage%3a).

```
[myNSBox somehowSetBackgroundColor: [NSColor colorWithPatternImage: myImage]];
```

Comment: NSImage *image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"spiderman.jpg"];
 [imageView setImage:image];
 [box setFillColor:[NSColor colorWithPatternImage:image]];     I tried above code...but it is not working

Comment: @Swap there are a bunch of reasons as to why that could be. Try isolating the issue: is `image` a valid NSImage, with the right data? Does `[box setFillColor: [NSColor redColor]]` work?

Comment: [box setFillColor: [NSColor redColor]] is not working...I m checking the reasons

Comment: [This MacRumors thread](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=518454) seems to have some insight :)